# List of users based on Description in Active Directory using Powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm basically new to PowerShell. May I ask what do I need to do in Get-ADUser -filter.. to pull out users that have the same description?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties Description | Select Name,Description | Sort Description
```

You could add another pipe to Format-List or Format-Table or export with Export-CSV or Export-CliXML

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `Group-Object` cmdlet to group object together with the same description.

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties Description |
    Select-Object Name,Description | 
    Group-Object Description |
    Where-Object {$_.count -gt 1}
```